# Eliminate declaration of xml file

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

I'm creating an XML file in Delphi 7. I want to remove the declaration of the parent node from the code.

This is my code:

```pascal
var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('p:test');
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns:ds'] := 'Attributes1';
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns:p'] := 'Attributes2';
  RootNode.Attributes['versione'] := 'FPR12';

  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('HeadNode');

  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('SubNode');
  CurNode.Text := 'Test';
  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('Codice');
  CurNode.Text := '01234567890';
  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  s := 'C:\Users\web\Desktop\file.xml';
  XMl.SaveToFile(s);
end;
```

This is my Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:test xmlns:ds="Attributes1" xmlns:p="Attributes2" versione="FPR12">
  <p:HeadNode>
    <p:SubNode>Test</p:SubNode>
    <p:Codice>01234567890</p:Codice>
  </p:HeadNode>
</p:test>
```

This is what I expected to have (note the missing "p:" on HeadNode and its nested nodes):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:test xmlns:ds="Attributes1" xmlns:p="Attributes2" versione="FPR12">
  <HeadNode>
    <SubNode>Test</SubNode>
    <Codice>01234567890</Codice>
  </HeadNode>
</p:test>
```

How can I get this?

Comment: declare an empty namespace on node `HeadNode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior, any node that is created under a parent node will carry the namespace of the parent node. Since you want that Node `HeadNode`does not carry a namespace, you must assign an empty namespace when you create that node. If you look at function [`TXMLNode.AddChild`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.AddChild), you will see that there is an overload function that accepts a second parameter that represents the `NameSpaceUri` for that node.
So to fix your XML, all you have to do is change line `CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('HeadNode');` into `CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('HeadNode', '');`

Compilable example:

```
program SO58008911;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  ActiveX,
  XMLIntf,
  XMLDoc,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure TestXML;
var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('p:test');
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns:ds'] := 'Attributes1';
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns:p'] := 'Attributes2';
  RootNode.Attributes['versione'] := 'FPR12';
  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('HeadNode', '');
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('SubNode');
  CurNode.Text := 'Test';
  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('Codice');
  CurNode.Text := '01234567890';
  Writeln(XML.XML.Text);
end;

begin
  try
   CoInitialize(nil);
   try
    TestXML;
   finally
    CoUninitialize;
   end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
 Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p:test xmlns:ds="Attributes1" xmlns:p="Attributes2" versione="FPR12">
  <HeadNode>
    <SubNode>Test</SubNode>
    <Codice>01234567890</Codice>
  </HeadNode>
</p:test>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to simply add an `xmlns` attribute to an XML node using its `Attributes[]` property, you need to actually *declare* the namespace within the DOM tree.  `IXMLNode` has a [`DeclareNamespace()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.DeclareNamespace) method for that purpose.  When creating a child node, it inherits the namespace of its parent node, but not if you don't declare the namespace correctly to begin with.

Also, because your root `test` node has 2 namespaces declared in it, you need to specify which namespace the `HeadNode` child actually belongs to.  If you don't, it inherits the same prefix as its parent node so it can indicate which namespace it is in, which is what you are seeing happen.

Try this instead:

```pascal
var
  XML : IXMLDocument;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)

  RootNode := XML.AddChild('p:test');
  RootNode.DeclareNamespace('ds', 'Attributes1');
  RootNode.DeclareNamespace('p', 'Attributes2');
  RootNode.Attributes['versione'] := 'FPR12';

  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('HeadNode', 'Attributes2');

  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('SubNode');
  CurNode.Text := 'Test';
  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('Codice');
  CurNode.Text := '01234567890';
  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  CurNode := CurNode.ParentNode;

  s := 'C:\Users\web\Desktop\file.xml';
  XML.SaveToFile(s);
end;
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p:test xmlns:ds="Attributes1" xmlns:p="Attributes2" versione="True">
  <HeadNode xmlns="Attributes2">
    <SubNode>Test</SubNode>
    <Codice>01234567890</Codice>
  </HeadNode>
</p:test>
```